# React Router v6 not showing nested route - what am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have in my index the following routes:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
            <Route path="admin" element={<AdminDashboard /> } />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

I can access `/` and `admin`, and the components render correctly.

Inside `AdminDashboard`, I have two other routes:

```
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<AdminCards />} />
            <Route path="news-sources" element={<NewsSourcesAdmin /> } />
        </Routes>
```

If I access `http://localhost/` and `http://localhost/admin`, I get things to render correctly.

However, if I attempt to go to `http://localhost/admin/news-sources`, then the `NewsSourcesAdmin` component does not render. I get an empty page instead.

Shouldn't the `AdminDashboard` component render given I'm under the `admin` route, and then the `NewsSourcesAdmin` component render inside of it given I am under the `/admin/news-sources` route?

I am on React 17, React Router v6.

What am I missing?

Comment: `"news-sources"` → `"/news-sources"`?

Comment: @szaman no, unfortunately that yields the same blank page...

Comment: update route path for ```AdminDashboard``` ```admin/*```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v6 routes are exact by default.
Use trailing `*` to match everything:

```
<Route path="admin/*" element={<AdminDashboard /> } />
```